# Vue 3 component stops working when included in a parent component's template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm working with a very simple Vue 3 app, listed below.

Due to the nature of our project, we want use in-DOM templates.

This works fine for a single component.
But once a child component is added, this component does not work.

See the example below, where `SubComponent` stops working when we enable the `createApp` for the `App` component.

I've tried using slots, experimented with registering as components, but none of these work.

What am I overlooking?

```js
const {ref} = Vue;

const SubComponent = {
  setup() {
    const text = ref("");
    return {
      text
    };
  }
};

const App = {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = () => {
      count.value++;
    };

    return {
      count,
      inc
    };
  }
}


Vue.createApp(SubComponent).mount("#subcomponent");
Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello Vue 3!</h1>
    <button @click="inc">Clicked {{ count }} times.</button>
    <div id="subcomponent">
      <h2>Hello from subcomponent</h2>
      <input v-model="text" />
      <br />
      <span>{{text}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like following snippet:

```js
const {ref} = Vue;

const SubComponent = {
  template: `
    <h2>Hello from subcomponent</h2>
    <input v-model="text" />
    <br />
    <span>{{text}}</span>
  `,
  setup() {
    const text = ref("");
    return { text };
  }
};

const App = {
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = () => {
      count.value++;
    };
    return { count, inc };
  }
}
Vue.createApp(App)
  .component('SubComponent', SubComponent)
  .mount('#app')
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello Vue 3!</h1>
    <button @click="inc">Clicked {{ count }} times.</button>
    <sub-component></sub-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola! This works like a charm, but we cannot use templates *inside* of the component declaration in our project. If I remove the template from the example above, it stops working. I've tried using a slot, so replacing the template above with `template: "<slot></slot>"` -- then the component renders but the text property is not used and the span doesn't update on change.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest multiple vue apps, you only have one app and within it you can have multiple or nested components. Not sure with the approach having everything in one file though.

```js
const {ref} = Vue;

const SubComponent = {
  setup() {
    const text = ref("");
    return {
      text
    };
  }
};

const App = {
  components: {
    SubComponent,
  },
  setup() {
    const count = ref(0);
    const inc = () => {
      count.value++;
    };

    return {
      count,
      inc
    };
  }
}


Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>Hello Vue 3!</h1>
    <button @click="inc">Clicked {{ count }} times.</button>
    <sub-component>
      <h2>Hello from subcomponent</h2>
      <input v-model="text" />
      <br />
      <span>{{text}}</span>
    </sub-component>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I get what you're saying. The example however, does not seem to work; the sub-component does not render.